# Reload entity that has been modified in another context

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Let's say I have this code, using EF6 and WPF

```
// db model
class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}

// db model
class Bar
{
    public virtual Category { get; set; }
}

class Foo
{
    private Bar bar;

    void Load()
    {
        using(var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            bar = context.Bars.First(x => x.Id == 1);
        }
    }

    void Mutation()
    {
        using(var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
             context.Attach(bar);
             bar.Category.Name = "Hello";
             context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}

class Baz
{
    private Bar bar;

    void Load()
    {
        using(var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            bar = context.Bars.First(x => x.Id == 1);
        }
    }

    void Print()
    {
        // Reload entity???
        Console.WriteLine(bar.Category.Name);
    }
}
```

Now let's say I instanciate both `Foo` and `Baz`. Both of their instance of `bar` have been loaded by different contexts, but represent the same record in the database. If I were to call `Mutation()` on `Foo`, `bar.Category.Name` of `Baz` wouldn't be updated.

How would I go about reloading `Baz.bar`? I have tried almost everything I could find online with no success.

For example, this does not work

```
context.Entry(bar).Reload()
```

A single context for the whole application would fix this tracking issue, but it is considered bad practice. I hope I was clear enough!

Comment: I'd advise you to look into [DI](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615139/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Dependency-Inver) , also I do not see any `context.SaveChanges()` meaning nothing will persist changes to your DB

Comment: Going to look at this link, thanks. I added some bits of code, the SaveChanges are present in the real code

edit: after reading your link, I am unsure as what I should take out of it

Comment: What is `Category` ? I see you access it's `.Name` but you have not included it.

Comment: @Antry question updated

Comment: Are those your Entity models or POCO models ?

Comment: `context.Entry(bar).Reload()` should work. Please show how/where you tried it.

Comment: @Antry I am unsure of what you mean. They are my tables in code first (DbSet<Bar>, ...)

I cannot share the whole code as it is quiet large, but this example shows exactly what I am doing without the irrevelant parts.

Comment: Yeah basically I was asking if you were hitting on your `DbSet<Bar>` or on your `BarModel` class for example, that your [Repository Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) would manage.